# Is there a way to make a video repeat in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I added a video to my viewController() as a background and I want to loop it or in other words make it repeat itself forever.
Here is all the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "background", ofType: "mp4")!))
    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    layer.frame = view.bounds
    layer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    layer.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    layer.repeatDuration = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    player.play()

}
```

}

When I run the app It only plays once and never repeats itself.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to observe `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` and then simply restart the video.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, 
    object: player.currentItem, 
    queue: .main
) { [weak player] _ in
    player?.seek(to: .zero)
    player?.play()
}
```

Don't forget to detach this observer whenever it's no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use an AVPlayerLooper. Its name tells you that this is exactly what it's for.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlooper

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments.

1. According to AVPlayerLayer doc: Set one or the other. Not both.

> If both repeatDuration and repeatCount are specified the behavior is
> undefined.

2. In general, I've struggled with getting AVPlayerLayer to repeat mp4's using the repeatCount or repeatDuration way. Instead I use AVQueuePlayer with a AVPlayerLooper. Credit to: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658909

```swift
    import AVFoundation
    var playerQueue: AVQueuePlayer!
    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper!

    private func configLooper(file: String, ext: String) {
        guard let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: ext) else { return }

        playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer()
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem)
        playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, below: someOtherView.layer)
        playerQueue.play()
    }
```